# file compilation without the existence of a class having the same name as the name of file

Tags: java, compilation

I have a doubt in the following piece of code.although i saved the file as Newclass.java.It is not prompting me to make a public Newclass which it should since we always say the public class containing the main function should be the name of the file name. Why the converse doesnt hold? 
P.S. no errors in this code. works fine,output->called. I also understand that MAIN itself is a class. It has its class file in a package.

```
abstract class Base 
 {
 void fun()`{ }
 }

  class Derived extends Base 
 { 
  void hello()
{  
     System.out.println("derived called");
   }

   void fun() 
 {
     System.out.println(" called");
  }

    }

   class MAIN
 {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
   { 
     Base b = new Derived();
      b.fun();
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`since we always say the public class containing the main function should be the name of the file name.`

The name of the file should match the `public` class defined in the file. There can only be one `public` class per `.java` file. You have no `public` classes in your file so it can be named anything.

Comment: Yeah,i get it now! The class wasnt made public and it could have been named anything if it was not made a public class! Thanks Sotirios Delimanolis :)